# How to subtract rows by some conditions in df?

Tags: python, pandas

In the column "Test_method", there are three types, including FT, TZ and MM. I want to subtract the rows under FT and TZ by the rows under MM corresponding to the same Name. The sample of the dataset is shown in the image.

[samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YMk.jpg)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['CYH','CYH','CYH', 'DMH','DMH','DMH'],
                   'Test_method' : ['FT','FT','MM','FT','FT','MM'],
                   'Neck_cir' : [35.42, 35.48, 30.5, 37.04, 37.84, 36],
                   'Chest_cir' : [86.15, 86.75, 87, 83.11, 83.42, 85]})
```

output

```
| Name | Test_method | Neck_cir | Chest_cir |
|------|-------------|----------|-----------|
| CYH  | FT          | 4.92     | -0.85     |
| CYH  | FT          | 4.98     | -0.25     |
| DMH  | FT          | 1.04     | -1.89     |
| DMH  | FT          | 1.84     | -1.58     |
```

Comment: show us some sample data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Can you provide your data in text format in question?Screenshots/images are hard to convert.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry for the unclear question. This is the first time I ask question in Stackoverflow. I add the sample data and output here. I will do better next time. Thanks